# Why doesn't savePlot("file.pdf", type="pdf") work by default?

Tags: r

Does anyone know why savePlot can't save to pdf in linux by default?

```
> savePlot("rv-3.pdf", type="pdf")
Error in match.arg(type) : 
  'arg' should be one of “png”, “jpeg”, “tiff”, “bmp”


lizard:~images$ R --version
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?savePlot` is pretty clear about this:

> This works by copying the image surface to a file.

Hence you start with a raster representation and therefore can only go to a raster representation. It would be somewhat perverse to pipe a raster version of the plot in a PDF, which is a vector format (yes I know you *can* have rasters inside PDFs).

The functionality is limited to cario-based `X11` devices and the documentation refers to copying the "on screen" representation hence the restrictions.

I suppose the other Answer to your question is: that functionality has not been implemented yet.

Comment: Except it *does* work on R-windows.  I use R on Windows XP at home and on linux in the office. I was just saving plots to png, but discovered that savePlot("plot.pdf", type="pdf") (made at home) gave me much sharper graphs that didn't pixelate when expanded -- i.e. implying a vector format.  So for graphs going into documents I switched to using pdf.  I only discovered a couple of days ago that the same command which works on R-windows doesn't work on R-linux.  Of course it's not that hard to

   {pdf("file");
   source("file.r");
   dev.off()}

as suggested below, but I'm still curious.

Comment: Again, this is documented. See `Note` in `?savePlot` on Linux. This relates to the underlying R Graphics devices. `savePlot()` only works for cairo-based graphics devices on Linux, whilst on Windows, the `windows()` device is used. These are based on fundamentally different graphical toolkits and the functionality available or how the R devices are implemented most likely determines what is possible via the `savePlot()` idiom.

Comment: In other words, RTFM.  <:)

Thanks, that was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`dev.copy2pdf` does what you want:

```
plot(1:10)
dev.copy2pdf(file="~/test.pdf")
```

From reading the help files, I take it this will effectively replot your figure as a vector image in the file, which will usually be preferable to exporting your vector image into a raster format, as `savePlot` appears to do.

Comment: Great answer! +1 It provides the solution to pdf print once the plot is already plotted, while @cconnell answer requires the command `pdf(...)` before plotting and `dev.off()` afterwards. (Yet not answering why `savePlot` is so unable)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pdf(file="rv-3.pdf")
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

you can also change the size by by adding height= or width= to the pdf function.